# Docker port mapping change

Tags: postgresql, docker

My docker postgres instance can't be connected to from the internet.

I think it is because it is mapped by docker to localhost.

```
root@VM01:~/docker# docker port postgres
5432/tcp -> 127.0.0.1:5432
```

I am new to docker and I would like to try remapping that to

```
5432/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:5432
```

To see if I can then connect remotely over the internet.

```
root@VM01:~/docker# netstat -na | grep 5432
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5432          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

Does anyone have experience doing this or advice on if this might work...?

I have another docker instance on the same host that reflects 0.0.0.0:8000 and using telnet from any machine on the internet shows it is accessible.

Not this one though:

`127.0.0.1:5432->5432/tcp`

Comment: What does docker logs show you?

Comment: If you want to change a Docker-level setting, you typically need to delete and recreate the container (if you've correctly set up persistent storage for the database then you won't lose data).  How did you originally start the container?  What is your host OS?